# Telerik reports date input control doesn't work in html5 report viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, telerik

My reports and date input controls used to work but after certain update (still trying to figure it out which one) I'm unable to make them work. I can totally continue using my reports by manually entering the date and hit the `preview` button, but I need to fix the date input control.

When the report page (report viewer) is loaded I can see these calls:

```
POST http://localhost:xxxx/api/reports/clients/xxxxxx-xxxx/parameters 
POST http://localhost:xxxx/api/reports/clients/xxxxxx-xxxx/instances
```

First is `OK` (200) and second gives me `Not Found` (404)
Both has the same payload:

```
parameterValues : {}
report : "MyCoolReport, MyCoolApp.WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

And then when I click on the date control it gives me the following JS error and popup is not opened:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function
    at M.fn.init.offset (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at init._position (kendo.subset.2015.3.930.min.js:3)
    at init.open (kendo.subset.2015.3.930.min.js:3)
    at j.open (kendo.subset.2015.3.930.min.js:3)
    at j.toggle (kendo.subset.2015.3.930.min.js:3)
    at init._click (kendo.subset.2015.3.930.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSpanElement.e (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSpanElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

is it something with my Telerik setup or I've updated the libraries to some unsupported version (like jquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I was right. jQuery 1.9.1 is required:
http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-report-viewer-system-requirements

Now my date controls work just fine but the API call to `instances` still fails (I'm not sure what it affects as long as everything continues to work).